# Saving text out of a struct in a char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

I have a struct with letters inside and **I want to give the letters to an array** so i can use it afterwards. It works if i would just print the letters.

Top (struct):

```
 #include "stdafx.h"

typedef struct { char* code; char* letter;}morse_tabelle; 

morse_tabelle tabelle[] = {
    { ".-", "A" },
    { "-...", "B" },
    { " -.-. ", "C" },
    { "-..", "D" },
    { ".", "E" },
    { "..-.", "F" },
    { "--.", "G" },
    { "....", "H" },
    { "..", "I" },
    { ".---", "J" },
    { "-.-", "K" },
    { ".-..", "L" },
    { "--", "M" },
    { "-.", "N" },
    { "---", "O" },
    { ".--.", "P" },
    { "--.-", "Q" },
    { ".-.", "R" },
    { "...", "S" },
    { "-", "T" },
    { "..-", "U" },
    { "...-", "V" },
    { ".--", "W" },
    { "-..-", "X" },
    { "-.--", "Y" },
    { "--..", "Z" },
    { "-----", "0" },
    { ".----", "1" },
    { "..---", "2" },
    { "...--", "3" },
    { "....-", "4" },
    { ".....", "5" },
    { "-....", "6" },
    { "--...", "7" },
    { "---..", "8" },
    {"----.", "9" },
    { "/", " " },
    };
```

For the arraysize:

```
#define ARR_SIZE(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]))
```

Function:

```
    void morse_to_text(void)
    {


    char input[100];
    char* morse_letter;

    int j = 0;
    char* translation[50];


    printf_s("\n\nput in Morsecode:\n\n");
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);                                             
    input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';                                       

    morse_letter = strtok(input, " ");                               

    while (morse_letter)                                                      
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE(tabelle); i++)                            
        {

            if (!strcmp(morse_letter, tabelle[i].code))                  
            {
                translation[j] = tabelle[i].letter;                    
                j++;
                /*printf_s("%s", tabelle[i].letter);*/   //This works              
            }
        }
        morse_letter = strtok(NULL, " ");                            
    }

    /*output*/
    printf_s("\n\n---------------\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(translation[50]); i++){
            printf("%s", translation[i]);
    }

};
```

It sort of works if i change the `char* letter` to `char letter` inside of the struct. but then i get a buffer overrun.
The question again: how can i store strings inside an array.

Comment: Your code looks like pure C to me. What the C++ tag?

Comment: What's `strlen(translation[50])`?

Comment: `input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';` this is wrong

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(translation[50]); i++)` -> `for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)`

Comment: use `break`  after `j++` in `for` loop for efficiency

Comment: Your morse code for "C" has surplus spaces at each end.

Comment: @n.caillou I think that is to eliminate the line feed that is read in, too, with fgets. One should prefer to check, though, if it *really* is the line feed... Alternative would have been using `strtok(..., " \t\r\n")`...

Comment: @Binary_10 good idea, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you actually want is this:

```
char translation[50]; // no string array, char array!
```

Then have the letter as char as you intended:

```
typedef struct { char* code; char letter;} morse_tabelle;
```

With that, you now can simply do

```
translation[j] = tabelle[i].letter;
```

again, just as before. Only the data type changed...

However, you need to null-terminate your translated string, else you cannot use it with `printf("%s", translation)`

```
while(...) { ... }
translation[j] = 0;

// output:
// no for loop any more!

printf("%s", translation);
```

An alternative to terminating the null character would be giving the length to the printf format parameter:

```
while(...) { ... }
// no termination any more...

// output:
// no for loop any more!

printf("%.*s", j, translation);
```

See [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for details (OK, link actually is C++, but documentation is exactly true for C, too...).

Comment: Same answer as mine but slightly better laid out and includes detail of null termination which I missed since I took it for granted.

Comment: i tried it similar before, the biggest problem was that i didnt terminate the translation-array with a 0, so i got a bufferoverload i guess. now with this it works well

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
translation[j] = tabelle[i].letter;
```

do:

```
translation[j] = tabelle[i].letter[0];
```

Or instead, and even better, do:

```
typedef struct { char* code; char letter;} morse_tabelle; 

morse_tabelle tabelle[] = {
    { ".-", 'A' },
    { "-...", 'B' },
    { " -.-. ", 'C' },
    { "-..", 'D' },
    etc. etc.

char translation[50];
...
printf("%s\n", translation);
```

Or, if you want to print out the translation letter by letter:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(translation); i++)
{
    printf("%c\n", translation[i]);
}
```

To add some basic C tuition:

`char *` is a pointer to an array of `char` types. `"A"` is a `char` array with two elements and can be written as `{ 'A', '\0' }`. Hence assigning `"A"` to a `char` type is wrong.

If you define `letter` as a `char *` and populate the data with a one character string, then you can access the character by indexing the 0th element as `letter[0]`. However, rather than using character arrays all over the space and wasting memory and over-complicating your code, it is better just to use characters instead.

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. Rethink it please.

Comment: It would be nice if you would point out exactly which part of this answer is not correct. In truth the original code is so full of bugs that it needs a complete rewrite for a fully correct answer and I don't have time for that.

Comment: You write _Instead of: translation[j] = tabelle[i].letter; do: translation[j] = tabelle[i].letter[0];_, but this implies that you __need also__ modify what you have described under _Or, even better do:_.

Comment: @Michael Walz, thanks. It was correct, just a question of unclear text. There was an implicit "instead" in the second option that I have now made explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(translation[50]); i++) {
```

`strlen(translation[50]` is wrong. `translation` is an array of 50 pointers to `char*`. So `strlen(translation[50])` is the length of the 50th translated character (which BTW only exists if you have typed in 50 morse codes) and not the number of elements you've put into the `translation` array. You've put `j` `char*` pointers into the `translation` array, therefore the correct code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < j); i++) {
```

Comment: `translation[50]` actually asks for the 51th element

Comment: @n.caillou yes if you start at 1.

Comment: this was a good example for me to understand pointers a bit more, thank you.